# vuejs mounted lifecycle not triggering

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

in my App component below, mounted() lifecycle hook is not triggered:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if='signedIn'>
        <router-view />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import Oidc from 'oidc-client'

Vue.use(Oidc)

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      user: null,
      signedIn: false,
      mgr: new Oidc.UserManager({...settings...})
    }
  },
  methods: {
    signIn () {
    },
    signOut () {
    },
    getUser () {
    },
    mounted () {
      this.getUser()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I have gone through the code several times, not sure what I'm missing. 
I have this in the main.js file:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  router
})
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You have the `mounted` inside the `method` area and this means that is a 'function' called mounted (like `getUser()`), not the `mounted` that automatically called when the component mounts.

You should change it like:

```
methods: {
    signIn () {
    },
    signOut () {
    },
    getUser () {
    }   
  },
mounted () {
      this.getUser()
}
```

And then it should work and be called automatically by Vue as a normal lifecycle method.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I missed that

Comment: @capiono, don't worry, done that myself a few times!

Comment: @RameshPareek you should create a separate question to your specific case & share some information about your issue. This was answered like 2 years ago, it's normal that this is not your case. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, @JP.Aulet, :) You are right. :) but I shall add something for future visitors, I made a silly mistake. I actually created two `mounted()` lifecycle hooks in the same component. Due to this, somehow, no lifecycle hook was working.  As I removed the duplicate one, it worked like a charm.